# pyspark bitwiseAND vs ampersand operator

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to add a column to a dataframe that indicates when two different values are both found in a nested array

```
 expr1 = array_contains(df.child_list, "value1")
 expr2 = array_contains(df.child_list, "value2")
```

I got it to work with an ampersand operator

```
 df.select(...).withColumn("boolTest", expr1 & expr2)
```

Then I tried to replace this with `bitwiseAND` with the thought being, I would want to have a list of these expressions ANDed together dynamically.

This fails with an error

```
 df.select(...).withColumn("boolTest", expr1.bitwiseAND(expr2))

 cannot resolve ..... due to data type mismatch: '(array_contains(c1.`child_list`, 'value1') & 
array_contains(c1.`child_list`, 'value2'))' requires integral type, 
not boolean;;
```

What's the distinction and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The & and | operators work on BooleanType columns in pyspark operate as logical AND and OR operations.  In other words they take True/False as input and output True/False.

The bitwiseAND functions does bit by bit AND'ing of two numeric values.  So they could take two integers and output the bitwise AND'ing of them.

Here is an example of each:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

schema = StructType([   
  StructField("b1", BooleanType()), 
  StructField("b2", BooleanType()),
  StructField("int1", IntegerType()), 
  StructField("int2", IntegerType())
])
data = [
  (True, True, 0x01, 0x01), 
  (True, False, 0xFF, 0xA), 
  (False, False, 0x01, 0x00)
]

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(data), schema)


df2 = df.withColumn("logical", df.b1 & df.b2) \
        .withColumn("bitwise", df.int1.bitwiseAND(df.int2))

df2.printSchema()
df2.show()

+-----+-----+----+----+-------+-------+
|   b1|   b2|int1|int2|logical|bitwise|
+-----+-----+----+----+-------+-------+
| true| true|   1|   1|   true|      1|
| true|false| 255|  10|  false|     10|
|false|false|   1|   0|  false|      0|
+-----+-----+----+----+-------+-------+


>>> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- b1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- b2: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- int1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- int2: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- logical: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- bitwise: integer (nullable = true)
```

If you want to dynamically AND together a list of columns, you can do it like this:

```
columns = [col("b1"), col("b2")]
df.withColumn("result", reduce(lambda a, b: a & b, columns))
```

Comment: The lambda solution will certainly work.  My misunderstanding was I thought somehow the `bitwiseAND` function was connected to the overloading of the `&` operator, but I was wrong -- `bitwiseAND` is indeed a bitwise AND, even though the operator normally associated with bitwise AND acts in a logical capacity.